# Getting transaction list from Paypal Access

Tags: php, paypal

I'm using Paypal access to login. But after login I need the paypal transactions.

I used sample code from https://github.com/paypal/paypal-access
Everything worked fine. But I don't understand how to get the transactions. Is that possible using Paypal Access? if not then how to do it? You may take a look at http://www.storenvy.com/ . They pulled paypal transactions.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [TransactionSearch API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/transactionsearch-api-operation-nvp) combined with [GetTransactionDetails](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/gettransactiondetails-api-operation-nvp) to obtain everything you need.